# replace recursion to while loop

Tags: python, loops, recursion, while-loop

I'm trying to modify this recursive quicksort so that instead of using recursion, it uses a while loop and I need help.

```
def quicksort(array):
    less = []
    equal = []
    greater = []

    if len(array) > 1:
        i = array[0]
        for j in array:
            if j < i:
                less.append(j)
            if j == i:
                equal.append(j)
            if j > i:
                greater.append(j)
        return quicksort(less)+quicksort(equal)+quicksort(greater)  
    else:
        return array

def main():
    array=eval(input("Input the numbers you want to be sorted, in a random order: "))
    print(quicksort(array))
main()
```

Comment: Do you know how to unroll a recursive algorithm in general? Point is that nobody here will make your homework. At most, people will help you do your homework if you show some effort yourself first.

Comment: why are you using eval?